# Android - Run a system settings activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

If I run this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.Settings$NotificationAppListActivity"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I get this

[PICTURE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbOqg.png)

Instead,I want that the `startActivity(intent)` opens the activity that appears when I tap on the "Phone" view in the list

[PICTURE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNHmx.png)

How can I get this ? Thanks

Comment: The code was wrong, I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Use This..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

### Or Edit your code line 2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.Settings"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Because `ComponentName` method get 2 parameter 1. package name and 2. class name `ComponentName(String pkg, String cls)`  first one, package name is ok but class name `com.android.settings.Settings$NotificationAppListActivity` that means you want to open `Notification` settings

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I get the notification settings of the app i created, not the "Phone" one. But you are near to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```